# How to show users only some fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, access-rights

I have a user group called 'Manager'. This group can access the information of the employees who are in the same company with them. But I also want to show some specific information of the employee who are not in the same company.

This is the domain filter.

```
<field name="domain_force">
[('business_unit_id.id','in',[com.id for com in user.company_ids])]
</field>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.